# How to communicate between Classes in a hierarchy in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

With the inspiration coming from the idea that you can code anything, i tried my hand at a complicated CollectionView nested structure which goes as follows:

```
CustomCollectionViewController
--CustomCollectionViewCell
----CustomTableView
------CustomTableViewCell
--------CustomPickerView
```

---

In ***CustomCollectionViewController***, the main data feed comes from property:

```
var cardFeed: [String: [Card]] = [:]
```

***Card*** is my defined model and variable *cardFeed* is applied the usual way in ***UICollectionView*** Delegate & DataSource methods:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "card", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.card = self.cardFeed[string]![indexPath.row]
    cell.cardIndex = indexPath.row
}
```

---

From the delegate methods, cardFeed above sets a main property in  ***CustomCollectionViewCell*** used to update the interface:

```
var card: Card! {
    didSet{
        setupCard()
    }
}
```

The property card is also the data feed for ***UITableView*** Delegate & Datasource.

---

Everything works perfectly, everything shows up as it should. Except for the fact that when a user picks values from the ***CustomPickerView***, the main data feed, namely *cardFeed* defined in ***CustomCollectionViewController*** (shown above) must update!

My solution is this:

(1) Given that there are three components, define array that records changes in ***CustomPickerView*** selected rows and a call back method to pass down the variable:

```
var selectedRow: [Int] = [1, 0, 0] {
    didSet {
        if updateRow != nil {
            updateRow!(self.selectedRow)
        }
    }
}
var updateRow: ( ([Int]) -> () )?
```

(2) In ***CustomCollectionViewCell*** define another call back with an extra argument, to keep track of what cell actually sent the selected row array :

```
var passSelectedRow: (([Int], Int) -> ())?
```

which is called in tableViews cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
cell.updateRow = { selectedRow in
     self.passSelectedRow!(selectedRow, indexPath.row)
 }
```

(3) finally update cardFeed in ***CustomCollectionViewController*** cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
cell.passSelectedRow = { selectedRow, forIndex in
   if self.cardFeed[string]![indexPath.row].chosenFood[forIndex].selectedRow != selectedRow {
           self.cardFeed[string]![indexPath.row].chosenFood[forIndex].selectedRow = selectedRow
    }
}
```

But here is the problem, if i now add a didSet to cardFeed, it will create an infinite loop because cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called indefinitely. If i get the ***CustomCollectionViewCell*** reference anywhere other than cellForItemAtIndexPath, self.collectionView?.reload() does not work! Is there a way i can update my variable cardFeed in ***CustomCollectionViewController*** from the selected rows in ***CustomPickerView***?

Answer (score 2):

When communicating between objects it is bad practice to make the child object have a strong reference to its owner, that is how you end up with retain cycles and bugs.

Let's take a look at the two most common ways of communicating between objects: delegation and notification.

with delegation:

- Create a protocol for communicating what you want, in your example:

  ```
  protocol PickerFoodSelectedDelegate : class {

      func selected(row : Int, forIndex : Int)

  }
  ```
- Add `weak var selectionDelegate : PickerFoodSelectedDelegate` as a variable in the picker class
- In the tableView class, during `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, you assign `self` to `picker.selectionDelegate`
- You then create a similar structure for communicating between the table and the collection view.

The key part is that delegate references be declared as `weak`, to avoid retain cycles and bugs.

With notifications you can use `NotificationCenter.default` to post a notification with any object you want, in this case you would:

- Subscribe to a notification name you choose in the table view.
- Post a notification from the picker view when an option is chosen.
- When the table receives the notification, extract the object.
- Do the same from the table to the collection view.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Notifications are good for communication in a more general sense, possibly less so in the case. For passing data "up the chain" you could also consider using Swift closures.